# How to mount windows on linux with ntfs-3g

Tags: windows-7, linux, mount, ntfs

So I am trying to mount my windows partition on my arch linux partition and I am not sure what option to use under /dev/

I am using the ntfs-3g package from the official repos and the plan to run a command such as:

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/my_NTFS_partition /mount/point
```

But I am unsure what my_NTFS_partition should be. Any pointers on how to find it or what it might be called? This is a Windows 7 partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first starting point is usually the `/proc` file system:

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   2        0          4 fd0
   8        0   58615704 sda
   8        1     102400 sda1
   8        2   25600000 sda2
   8        3    5120000 sda3
   8        4   27791360 sda4
   8       16  488386584 sdb
   8       17  488385536 sdb1
```

Often you can guess by the reported size which disk resp. partition is which one.

If not, you can use `fdisk` as *root* to print out some more informations:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 55.9 GiB, 60022480896 bytes, 117231408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008e005

Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048    206847   204800  100M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         206848  51406847 51200000 24.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       51406848  61646847 10240000  4.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       61646848 117229567 55582720 26.5G 83 Linux
```

You can see, I have only Linux partitions, but in your case something like **HPFS/NTFS/exFAT** should pop up in the *Type* column.

This does only report the filesystem flag in the partition table -- you have no guarantee at all that the partition is really formatted accordingly!

More details about the partition itself can be gathered by the `file` utility:

```
# file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=ed703b01-f06f-4546-915d-33ff9f85074a
```

---

*All these commands are save to use, as they perform read operations only. But, as some of those only run as root, be very careful about e.g. typos. If you are paranoid, check first with e.g. `fdisk --help` that the version you have does not differ from third-party sources (as my answer).*

Answer (score 1):

The particular device you need to mount will vary depending on how the machine is set up, both based on what kind of drive it is and how it is partitioned. It's probably of the format /dev/sda1, where "a" changes for different disks, and the number changes for different partitions on the disk. You can just try and see what it will successfully mount as ntfs and find it that way.

Comment: Okay that is what I was thinking but could that be dangerous in any way?

Comment: It should just error out if the device is already mounted. If you want to be extra sure, you can just check the contents of /proc/mounts to see what's already mounted.